# Existe alguma biblioteca de processamento de linguagem natural (NLP) para o português?

Tags: inteligência-artificial

Eu tenho pesquisado bastante na interwebs, vi várias bibliotecas de **NLP** pra Python, Java, JavaScript, entre outras... Cada uma delas eram apenas para o inglês ou outras línguas. E já que a comunidade de língua portuguesa é tão extensa eu queria saber se eu estou pesquisando errado ou se realmente não existe nenhuma biblioteca voltada para o português, no que diz respeito ao **Processamento de Linguagem Natural**.

Independente da linguagem, existe alguma biblioteca de processamento de linguagem natural **(NLP)** ? E se não tem, por que a **comunidade de língua portuguesa** não investe tanto quanto outras comunidades?

Comment: Você pode usar esta [biblioteca](http://pypln.org/), pode lhe ajudar.

Comment: Uma opção open source que vale a pena dar uma olhada é a biblioteca spaCy que já tem modelo pronto para português. [https://spacy.io/models/pt](https://spacy.io/).